# DockerDesktopVM loops forever looking for "docker-proxy"

Tags: windows, proxy, hyper-v, docker-desktop, docker-daemon

I am trying to run Docker Desktop on windows (10 enterprise) with an hyper-v backend.

But when docker tries to start the daemon, the hyper-v managed vm `DockerDesktopVM` fails to reach `docker-proxy` looping on the message

> client: still waiting for docker-proxy after <and the time it's been trying>

It retries untill Docker Desktop gives up and tells me that it could not start Hyper-V Backend.

I've tried with a couple versions of docker desktop (3.5.2 and 3.6.0) which have proven to work on my coworkers's identical (supposedly) machines ...

Any idea on how to investigate/make this work is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue upgrading from 3.5.1 to 3.5.2 and we have solved the issue dropping the Hyper-V virtual machine.

You can do that on Docker Desktop -> Troubleshoot (bug icon) -> Reset to factory defaults.

You will loose all your images, containers and volumes and you need to rebuild your projects.
But docker will work as expected.